# Envoy TCP traffic shifting only for new connections

Tags: reverse-proxy, istio, envoyproxy, trafficshaping

As per envoy official doc, TCP traffic shifting is possible with the weighted cluster. I have a case where TCP traffic shifting is needed from clusters A to B only for the new TCP connections. I have a WebSocket connection active in the working environment from `client -> envoy-> cluster A`. Since I do not want to break the WebSocket connection, can I shift only the new connections to cluster B and keep the traffic routing active to cluster A until all the active connections are drained out?

Answer (score 0):

Received the response from the envoy-dev team and also tested out the scenario. Only the new connections will be routed to the newly added cluster, and existing connections will remain as is.
By setting appropriate drain and parent shutdown time (https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/cli#cmdoption-parent-shutdown-time-s), one can safely make the WebSocket connection non-disruptible.